# How to get download/edit count of a file in SharePoint library using javascript?

Tags: javascript, events, download

If a file in SharePoint library has been downloaded 5 times, then I need get that download count of the file.

Additionally I need to get the same for counts of editing done for the file.

Answer (score 2):

### **Edit count**:

Use versioning, and show the version number. When using only Major versions, the version number will incrementally increase +1 each time the document is revised.

### **Download count**:

**Note**: this isn't available for O365/SharePoint Online!

In your Site Collection's root's site settings, navigate to *Site Collection Audit Settings*. Enable the auditing for at least "Opening or downloading documents, viewing items in lists, or viewing item properties" of "Document and Items"-section. The actual Audit Logs can be accesses also at Site Collection's root's site settings by navigating to *Audit Log reports*.

There isn't a trivial way to show this number directly in your SharePoint library by the documents. Through manipulating the Audit Logs and mirroring them to SharePoint, the properties (title, download count) *maybe* could be associated with your document library's documents using Lookup Columns. However, I'm not aware of a documentation doing this, nor have I done it myself.